Copying a dynamic panel from one checklist to another in SurveyJS
For one of our customers we set up Dynamics 365 CE CRM and also integrated SurveyJs into it. They want to create checklists using SurveyJS and to store them in Dynamics 365CE. Now I'd like to know if it's possible to copy a dynamic panel (with a set of questions) from one checklist to another. I saw that I could use the JSON editor within a checklist to copy whatever is there and paste it in the other checklist but I was wondering if there's an easier way?

If you wish to copy a Dynamic Panel definition, you can use the following options.

Manually copy a JSON definition of a Dynamic Panel

Copy the corresponding Dynamic Matrix JSON definition and insert it within another survey JSON definition.

Use JS to copy and load a target Dynamic Panel definition

Create a SurveyModel from the source JSON. Obtain a Dynamic Panel instance using the survey.getQuestionByName function. Call the toJSON() function for the Dynamic Panel object. You'll get a JSON object which describes the Dynamic Panel definition. To apply this definition to another Dynamic Panel, use the fromJSON() function.
